# Bootstrapping with 1-NN classifier

Tags: bootstrap, k-nearest-neighbour

Given the naive bootstrap estimate of the error of a classifier defined as:

$$\frac{1}{N}\frac{1}{B}\sum_{b=1}^{B}\sum_{i=1}^{N} L(y_i, \hat{c}_b(x_i))$$

Where $L(y, c(x)) = \mathbb{1}\{c(x)=y\}$ is the binary classification loss and $\hat{c}_b$ is the 1-NN classifier fitted by the $b$th bootstrap set. What is the error estimate of the above expression as the number of samples tends to infinite $N \rightarrow{} \infty$? How can I prove that the above error estimate does not provide a good estimate for the true prediction error?